# Python Itertools Combinatinos retrieving empty list

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I am trying to generate a list or dataframe with combinations of [0 , 1] for 14 different places. However

I am getting an empty list or a message of :

> [itertools.combinations at 0x29b294cc0e8]

There are actually a few solutions for the problem which I tried, none appear to work.

```
d = [0, 1]

result = itertools.combinations(d, 14)
for each in result:
    print(each)

results = [x for x in itertools.combinations(d, 14)]
```

From my calculations I should get a list of 2^ 14 combinations (16384) of zeros and ones.

Comment: did you mean repetitions or permutations of certain length? For 2 : 00,01,10,11 etc

Comment: I mean repetitions I suppose, ie, 14 places with all possible combinations of either 1 or 0.

Comment: Post a desired result output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compute all possibilities for an array of numbers/bits (in python, or any language for that matter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986272/how-do-i-compute-all-possibilities-for-an-array-of-numbers-bits-in-python-or-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code required is :

```
import itertools
d = [0, 1]
lst = list(itertools.product(d, repeat=14))
```

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.combinations (iterable, [r])` - combinations of length `r` from `iterable` *without duplicate* elements.
But you only have 2 elements, and you want a sequence of 14 elements long.
Perhaps worth using `itertools.combinations_with_replacement`.

Comment: Not quite this, see Santosh's answer above please

Answer (score 0):

Please try `combinations_with_replacement` since the 0, 1 are repeatable.

```
import itertools as it
results = list(it.combinations_with_replacement([0,1], 14))
```

results:

```
[(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
 (0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
 (0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
 (0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)]
```

Comment: Not quite this, see Santosh's answer above please

Comment: Got it. If the requirement is cartesian product of 2^14 instead of combinations, yep, the mentioned with itertools.product() generates 16384  elements.

Comment: Yes, apologies my initial formulation was not correct. That's it